# Googlebot checks my comments every 7 seconds

Tags: web-crawler, bots, googlebot

Don't know where else to ask, but from one day to the other my Wordpress website gets 500 spam comments a day. No probem, I have added a spamblocker.
Now I have checked the visitors of my website and I noticed that googlebot checks /wp-comments-post.php 7 times a minute.
Is this a problem? And how to solve this?

Comment: Only you know if it's a problem - can your webserver not handle the load? <pedant>every 7 seconds != 7 times a minute</pedant>

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem :-) I've never seen this.

Comment: @Justmac I wouldn't worry about it... WordPress has powerful enough servers to handle the load. If you're seeing any performance issues, then it would be a problem, but getting crawled by the google bot once every 9 seconds is hardly enough traffic to cause a dent in your site's performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it unless:

1. The added load is slowing down your site
2. Googlebot isn't getting to other pages because it's in some sort of loop (i.e. spider trap)

[Social is a big initiative for Google](http://pandodaily.com/2012/01/24/larry-page-to-googlers-if-you-dont-get-spyw-work-somewhere-else/) this year and they've recently been seen [crawling and indexing Facebook comments](http://searchengineland.com/many-facebook-comments-now-being-indexed-by-google-99399). So it make sense that they're also interested in Wordpress comments.

If you're really concerned or if it's impacting your site negatively, you can always block that page in your robots.txt, and Googlebot won't hit it anymore.